# SoundManager w HTML5 Audio is causing 206 Partial Content errors?

Tags: html, html5-audio, soundmanager2

I'm using SoundManager (SM) with HTML 5 audio preferred along with the standard SM flash fallback.

For some reason I'm seeing requests being cancelled, resulting in the error red in console though sounds play just fine.

Any idea why? Is this standard with CDNs or maybe HTML5 audio? Anyone seen this before? Thanks

```
Request URL:https://hall.com/misc/sounds/message_sent.mp3
Request Method:GET
Status Code: 206 Partial Content (from cache)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's an issue with the server hosting the MP3s, not with SoundManager2. The server doesn't appear to support Partial Content (i.e. byte-range requests). You can read more about [what is required for Partial Content support](http://httpstatus.es/206) or you can set the `stream` property on your sound object to `false` or with SoundManager's `defaultOptions`. Doing this will *suggest* that the browser request the audio data **without** the `Accept-Ranges: bytes` HTTP header.

```
soundManager.defaultOptions = {
  stream: false
}
```